# I want to make my pytest unittests run with the "python setup.py test" command

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

In the default behaviour giving the command `python setup.py test` will execute the unit tests associated with a module. This default behaviour can be made to work simply by providing a list of test-suite modules.

The alternative (but now obsolete) Nose test runner has a comparable feature - you can just provide the string `nose.collector` which gives the test command the ability to auto-discover the tests associated with the project.

But what if I'm using pytest? There doesn't seem to be a documented pattern to run tests from the setup.py file. Is this a behaviour supported by the pytest library?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally have not done this. But I'd recommend checking out some legit python projects on github to see how they have done this.
E.g. [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/setup.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand


class PyTest(TestCommand):
    user_options = [('pytest-args=', 'a', "Arguments to pass into py.test")]

    def initialize_options(self):
        TestCommand.initialize_options(self)
        self.pytest_args = []

    def finalize_options(self):
        TestCommand.finalize_options(self)
        self.test_args = []
        self.test_suite = True

    def run_tests(self):
        import pytest

        errno = pytest.main(self.pytest_args)
        sys.exit(errno)

setup(
    # pass all the required/desired args
    cmdclass={'test': PyTest}
)
```

You can even pass args to pytest runner `python setup.py test --pytest-args='-vvv'`

Also checkout the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner (thanks to @jonrsharpe for the link)