# Passing Arguments to pytest from setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py

I have tests that require arguments, in my case these are credentials to some service:

example_test.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def artuser(pytestconfig):
    return pytestconfig.getoption("artuser")
@pytest.fixture()
def artpass(pytestconfig):
    return pytestconfig.getoption("artpass")

def test_nuget_get_nuget(artuser, artpass):
    assert artuser == "someuser"
    assert artpass == "somepassword"
```

conftest.py:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--artuser", action="store")
    parser.addoption("--artpass", action="store")
```

It works if I run:
`pytest --artuser someuser --artpass somepassword`.
However, it fails if run:
`python setup.py test --artuser someuser --artpass somepassword`
with an an error `error: option --artuser not recognized`

I then tried to integrate some code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57449887/3501205) question, just to see if the argument gets passed along, so I have something like this in my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import path
import argparse
import sys

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('--artuser', help='required artuser argument', required=True)
args, unknown = argparser.parse_known_args()
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + unknown
print(args)

setup(
   name='myapp',
   ...
```

But when I run the tests, I get `E       AssertionError: assert None == 'someuser'`
meaning the argument wasn't passed along.

Comment: FYI, the `test` command for `setuptools` is being [deprecated](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1684), so I wouldn't rely on it for running any of your tests going forward

Comment: What is the alternative then?

Comment: Just run the tests with pytest. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: because if the tests require a module, setup.py knows to automatically resolve those

Comment: You should be installing your package with test dependencies before running pytest anyway.

Comment: The point of the setup.py tests_require= keyword parameter is to automate the installation of testing dependencies in just the same way that install_requires= does for package installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43924004/3501205).

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand
import sys
...

class PyTest(TestCommand):
    user_options = [('artuser=', 'a', "Artifactory user"),
                    ('artpass=', 'b', "Artifactory password")]

    def initialize_options(self):
        TestCommand.initialize_options(self)
        self.artpass = None
        self.artuser = None

    def finalize_options(self):
        TestCommand.finalize_options(self)
        self.test_args = []
        self.test_suite = True

    def run_tests(self):
        import pytest

        errno = pytest.main(
            ["--artuser", self.artuser, "--artpass", self.artpass])
        sys.exit(errno)

setup(
    cmdclass={
        'test': PyTest,
    },
    ...
```